# Slow file look up for large directories

Tags: java, file-io, directory, operating-system

If i create a file object of a file from a directory having half a million files, will the look up and opening of that file be slow ? If yes then whats the reason behind that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance usually begins to degrade when you have something on the `order` of tens of thousands of files, so yes, half a million files will probably kill your computer - this seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Amir thanks a ton for the fast rply but the issue bothering me is, does jvm tries to match the file path with the object to each and every files in the location before opening it ?

Comment: @ShashankShekhar No, the operating system does the search. So it depends on the operating system (e.g. Windows, Linux, Mac OS X) and the filesystem (e.g. NTFS, ext4).

Comment: @ShashankShekhar, the JVM delegates to the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I did some measurements using Java 1.6 on Linux 2.6.32 (avoided JIT-compiler noise) on file open and directory listing.  Opening a random file should be O(logN) per [this](https://superuser.com/questions/444286/linux-accessing-thousands-of-files-in-hash-of-directories), but there is no measurable slow down upto 1 million files:

```
Opened random file in /tmp/fubar.100 in 0 ms
Last modified at 1385629306000
Opened random file in /tmp/fubar.1000 in 0 ms
Last modified at 1385631078000
Opened random file in /tmp/fubar.10000 in 0 ms
Last modified at 1385631054000
Opened random file in /tmp/fubar.100000 in 0 ms
Last modified at 1385630478000
Opened random file in /tmp/fubar.1000000 in 0 ms
Last modified at 1385632681000
```

It appears the performance of File.listFiles() is O(n):

```
Listed 104 files in /tmp/fubar.100 in 2 ms
Listed 1001 files in /tmp/fubar.1000 in 9 ms (5x)
Listed 10001 files in /tmp/fubar.10000 in 19 ms (2x) 
Listed 100006 files in /tmp/fubar.100000 in 186 ms (10x)
Listed 1000002 files in /tmp/fubar.1000000 in 1909 ms (10x)
```

strace shows getdents() is called repeatedly O(n) times:

```
$ grep getdents err.100|wc
     28    5006   72926
$ grep getdents err.1000|wc
     33   44514  669558
$ grep getdents err.10000|wc
    147  441327 6765305
$ grep getdents err.100000|wc
   1213 4409107 68693705
$ grep getdents err.1000000|wc
  11987 44085454 701243406
```

Comment: ya this is quite obvious, as Robin said its dependent on the underline hardware, os and the filesystem as well. Thanks a lot for your effort @gabor, now i know the exact complexity of listing files. But i wanted to know the complexity of checking the existence of a file .

Comment: This looks pretty interesting, this is what i was thinking. For a random file access there shouldn't be a slow down. I really appreciate your work.

Comment: While it is dependent on underlying hardware and filesystem implementation, modern filesystems hash filenames (the ones listed above), so lookups are efficient O(log N).  On the flipside, alphabetical listing requires sorting O(N * log N).